# How to install HP printer on Elementary OS 6 Odin (HP LaserJet 1102W)

Tags: printer, hp

If you get this error with hp-setup?!

warning: elementary distro is not found in AUTH_TYPES

Comment: Thank you for offering a solution to this problem. As this is a Q&A site, could you [edit] your question to be *just* a question, then answer your own question with the solution? Not only will this help others who have the same problem, but it will ensure your question is not removed as being malformed 

Answer (score 0):

#1. Install "sudo apt install hplip" (also you can install also hplip-gui to get gui for installation, not just terminal) i do preffer just terminal install

#2. download latest .run and .asc files (I have installed: hplip-3.20.3-plugin.run, hplip-3.20.3-plugin.run.asc) from [here >> HP developers site](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/plugins)

#3. start from terminal sudo hp-setup -i, select 0 for usb, 1 for network

instead of D as download (you will get error), use P as path and enter your download directory of two previous files .acs and run, example: /home/your_username/Download

That's all, you can now print with HP, also you can find hplip toolbox manager in ElemetaryOS menu.